# How do I increment one value and reset another. PYTHON

Tags: python, oop

**I am searching for common terms in 2 decks of cards.
I want to search deck[v]...1 to deck[b]...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13.
I then want to increment [v] to search deck[v]...2 to deck[b]...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13.
etc etc etc
I can get the first part but can't figure out how to increment [v] and reset [b] to 1.
Any help would be appreciated.
Theres 13 terms**

```
b = 1
v = 1
while b <= 13:
    print(b, deck[b])
    print("Intersection between", "v = ",v, "and", "b = ",b, deck[v].intersection(deck[b]))
    if len(deck[v].intersection(deck[b])) == 1:
        print("1 match")
        print("v = ", v)
        print("b = ", b)
    b = b + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First off, putting your whole question in bold just makes it harder to read. It's not really clear what you mean by `deck[v]...1` and you haven't really described the problem you're trying to solve in terms of inputs and outputs. Please edit the question to improve the formatting, and clarify what specifically you're trying to do and why it doesn't work; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am basically just trying to increment V. And then run the loop again.

Comment: Incrementing a variable named `V` is easy - just write `V += 1`. Clearly, that is not a specific description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want v = 1, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13. Then I want v = 2, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13.

Comment: You are talking about the procedure you want your algorithm to follow. You need to explain what problem you are trying to solve. Give inputs and expected outputs. Provide sufficient information for someone to know whether their idea for an answer is correct or not. The question as it's currently written is not as clear as you might think it is.

Comment: @LeePriestEU, see my answer below - you should use 2 for loops (nested). That will keep one variable constant (b), increment through all the possibilities of the other (v), then increment (b) by 1 and repeat until all the possibilities of both variables have looped.

Comment: result of `deck[v].intersection(deck[b])` (if `deck[v]` and `deck[b]` are set datatype) already contain all matches. You don't need to perform `13*13` checks to print it

Comment: @LeePriestEU please kindly accept my answer if you found it useful or if it guided you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use 2 for loops?

```
for b in range(1,14):
 for v in range(1,14):
   # Your code
   print(b, deck[b])
   print("Intersection between", "v = ",v, "and", "b = ",b, deck[v].intersection(deck[b]))
   if len(deck[v].intersection(deck[b])) == 1:
      print("1 match")
      print("v = ", v)
      print("b = ", b)
```

Comment: You might also want to check out string formatting: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert your current code into a new loop and increment `v` in that loop:

```
b = 1
v = 1
while v <= 13:
    while b <= 13:
        print(b, deck[b])
        print("Intersection between", "v = ",v, "and", "b = ",b, deck[v].intersection(deck[b]))
        if len(deck[v].intersection(deck[b])) == 1:
            print("1 match")
            print("v = ", v)
            print("b = ", b)
        b = b + 1
    v = v + 1
```